# The best worst case scenario in MasterMind

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

In [the game of MasterMind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)), you are trying to guess a sequence of colours.  After each guess, your guess is graded: you find out how many are exactly right, and how many others are the right colour but out of sequence.

In an actual game, it's possible to get very lucky and simply guess the correct answer on your first attempt.

In a computer simulation, on the other hand, it's possible for the computer to change the correct answer without telling you, as long as it doesn't contradict any previous information it has given you.  I.e. the computer is forcing a worst case scenario upon the guesser.  I've written just such a simulation here: https://github.com/IBwWG/cheatermind

My question for you is this: Is it possible, given a configuration of $C >= 2$ colours and $S >= 1$ slots, to determine a formula for the minimum number of moves one would have to make to win against a computer that's cheating this way?

For example, the simplest configuration (like a coin toss) would have $M(2,1) = 2$, because the first guess will always be wrong, leaving only one other possibility.  No matter what you guess, it will take a minimum of two guesses to win.

Comment: Can the sequence have the same color twice (or more than that)? This is something that always throws me off when I play...

Comment: @ArnaudD. absolutely.  And in this case, *each* duplicate is only counted once in the grade.  E.g. guess $aabc$ when the answer is $adea$, and you would get one "completely right" for the first $a$, and one "right but in the wrong position" for the second $a$ (leaving the $b$ and $c$ completely wrong.)  The guess $aaab$ would receive the exact same grade, because that third $a$ does not correspond to anything in the final solution.  The guess $aaaa$ would give you 2 "completely right" and 0 "right but in the wrong position."

Comment: BTW, something interesting I've found so far, trying to dig into this question: https://github.com/IBwWG/cheatermind/wiki/Analysis

Answer (score 1):

[MasterMind Revisited by Wayne Goddard](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.4415&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives a partial solution, for $f(2, k)$, plus a table of some values:

[image: Table of f(n, k) values]

But it's not clear whether $f(n, k)$ can be determined exactly.